# How to put an image as the navigation bar title

Tags: iphone

I want to put a .png image in the middle of the navigation bar instead of the title written in text. Could you please let me know how to do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 126, accepted):

Set the navigationItem's titleView

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
self.navigationItem.titleView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
```

Comment: what is the size of UIImage should be for title ?? i tried with 180*40 but it is getting blur.

Comment: This works perfect in iOS 7.1 (without 'autorelease', of course) The size of my image was 296x40px (2x) and it shows perfect. Thank you!

Comment: just add a tip. In swift the code would be:

let imgTitleBar = UIImage(named: "iphone-menu.png")
self.navItem.titleView = UIImageView(image: imgTitleBar)

Answer (score 42):

**Swift 4.2**

Includes suggested framing/scaling

```
let image: UIImage = UIImage(named: "image.png")!
let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 40, height: 40))
imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
imageView.image = image
self.navigationItem.titleView = imageView
```

Comment: Thank you @Michael-R ....But after i added the following code my navigation item title is not getting displayed

Comment: Swift and iOS have changed some since posting this answer, Ill try and give it a look soon

Comment: Man, you are awesome

Answer (score 14):

You can change all the views in a UINavigationBar. If you are trying to alter the navigationBar in a navigation controller do:

```
self.navigationItem.titleView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"] autorelease];
```

If you are creating the navigationBar yourself do the same, but in stead of calling `self.navigationItem` call: `navigationBar.topItem`

Comment: what is the size of UIImage should be for title ?? i tried with 180*40 but it is getting blur.

Answer (score 4):

In case if someone needs both image and text inside the Navigation bar title view in Swift 4.2, please try this function:-

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    //Sets the navigation title with text and image
    self.navigationItem.titleView = navTitleWithImageAndText(titleText: "Dean Stanley", imageName: "online")
}

func navTitleWithImageAndText(titleText: String, imageName: String) -> UIView {

    // Creates a new UIView
    let titleView = UIView()

    // Creates a new text label
    let label = UILabel()
    label.text = titleText
    label.sizeToFit()
    label.center = titleView.center
    label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center

    // Creates the image view
    let image = UIImageView()
    image.image = UIImage(named: imageName)

    // Maintains the image's aspect ratio:
    let imageAspect = image.image!.size.width / image.image!.size.height

    // Sets the image frame so that it's immediately before the text:
    let imageX = label.frame.origin.x - label.frame.size.height * imageAspect
    let imageY = label.frame.origin.y

    let imageWidth = label.frame.size.height * imageAspect
    let imageHeight = label.frame.size.height

    image.frame = CGRect(x: imageX, y: imageY, width: imageWidth, height: imageHeight)

    image.contentMode = UIView.ContentMode.scaleAspectFit

    // Adds both the label and image view to the titleView
    titleView.addSubview(label)
    titleView.addSubview(image)

    // Sets the titleView frame to fit within the UINavigation Title
    titleView.sizeToFit()

    return titleView

}
```

[image]

Comment: Amazing, I've been looking for this.

Answer (score 3):

Updated with Swift 2.x

```
navigationItem.titleView = UIImageView.init(image: UIImage(named:"yourImageName"))
```

Answer (score 2):

Swift 5 version:

```
navigationItem.titleView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "logo.png"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Searching for an answer to this question, I've found a nice and simple solution in the [Apple Discussions forum](http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?messageID=7951074), overriding `-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect` for `UINavigationBar` :

```
@implementation UINavigationBar (CustomImage)
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"NavigationBar.png"];
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)];
}
@end
```

Comment: I would say it is not the best solution, since the title can be set anyways and it is more like a hack but it can easily solve the problem and it works.