# How to include an image in the title of the navigation bar?

Tags: ios, image, navigation, storyboard

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to put an image as the navigation bar title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/865176/how-to-put-an-image-as-the-navigation-bar-title)

I am fairly new to programming in xcode and I am using storyboards. I have my navigation controller working perfectly and each viewcontroller has a word title. My question is how would I also add an image to that title without it being a separate icon on the navigation bar itself? When I drag the image over the navigation bar, it wants to create its own separate functionless button on either the right or left side of the navigation bar. Is there a way to add it to the title itself with the text string?

Comment: I'm sure you can't change the appearance/UI of Xcode.

Comment: Have you tried adding it as a subview in code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is already answered here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/865506/736384

Just create a UIImageView and assign it to the titleView of the navigationItem.

Comment: This does not work in iOS 6