# How to use an image logo on the navigation bar instead of title

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, storyboard, swift3

I have tried a couple different codes but couldn't make the logo show

```
import UIKit 
class HomeViewController: UIViewController { 

override func viewDidLoad() { 
super.viewDidLoad() 

let logo = UIImage(named: "logo.png") 
let imageView = UIImageView(image: logo) 
self.navigationItem.titleView = imageView
navigationItem.titleView?.sizeToFit() 
 } 
}
```

I even tried to include IB in the class itself didn't work either, it doesn't seem to work that way

```
@IBOutlet weak var navBar: UINavigationItem!
```

PS. My logo is a 200x40px png and its named logo.png in the assets.

My storyboard

http://i68.tinypic.com/b68t8o.png

Any help is appreciated

Edit: I solved my problem by putting an image view there instead of this whole navigation item story. Thanks for your suggestions though.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to put an image as the navigation bar title](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/865176/how-to-put-an-image-as-the-navigation-bar-title)

Comment: Thanks, but I tried the methods there but it didn't work either :/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

try this

```
 let logo = UIImage(named: "logo.png") 
 let imageView = UIImageView(image: logo) 
 imageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit // set imageview's content mode
 self.navigationItem.titleView = imageView
```

Answer (score 0):

Set your imageview's content mode like,

```
 imageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
```

Answer (score 0):

This code looks good, i think there is error in name of UIImage, did you debug and check that **let logo** is not **nil**? try to remove **".jpg"**

Answer (score 0):

**Use extension:**

```
extension UIViewController {
    func setNavigationBarLogo() {
        let logo = UIImage(named: "YourLogo.png")
         let imageView = UIImageView(image: logo)
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
         self.navigationItem.titleView = imageView
    }
}
```

**Usage in UIViewController:**

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.setNavigationBarLogo()
    }
```