# NavigationBar background image for iOS 10 XCode 8.1 Swift 3.0

Tags: ios, swift3, uinavigationbar

How to set the background image for this specific settings? `iOS10` and `XCode8.1`?
I tried everything below:

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "navigationBg")!.resizableImage(withCapInsets: UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0), resizingMode: .stretch), for: .default)
UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "navigationBg")! , for: .any, barMetrics: .default)
UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "navigationBg")! , for: .default)
```

I'm able to set the color of `navigationBar` using `storyboard` but unable to set the image.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Trying setting "self.navigationItem.titleView" property

Reference : [how-to-put-an-image-as-the-navigation-bar-title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/865176/how-to-put-an-image-as-the-navigation-bar-title)

**Update:**

Try this, instead of setting in UINavigationBar()

```
let navBackgroundImage:UIImage! = UIImage(named: "<navigationBarImage>")
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(navBackgroundImage,
                                                            for: .default)
```

Comment: I'm using this for the title image of navigation bar, not for the background though. I'll try combining both images and use this method. Thanks

Comment: Nope, this isn't the solution. It just places image on center of navigation bar. you can't set the image to cover whole navigation bar.

Answer (score 7):

Here is the code which perfectly work for me in Swift 3. 
Put this in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`.

```
let image = bg_banner // let image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "bg_banner")
UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(image.resizableImage(withCapInsets: UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0), resizingMode: .stretch), for: .default)
```

And here is the output which I received.
[image]

Answer (score 4):

To set NavigationBar Background Image you can write this:

```
 self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named:"pattern.png"),
                                                                for: .default)
```

Answer (score 3):

For setting up the background image to whole navigation bar use this cde in swift 3.0,

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "Exam-104")!.resizableImage(withCapInsets: UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)), for: .default)
```

[image: Navigation bar image]

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

***XCode 8.1 Swift 3.0 iOS 10***

*from Apple documentation:*

> *You can set a custom background image for your navigation bar. You can do this using `setBackgroundImage:forBarMetrics:`. Note that you
>   must specify bar metrics because navigation bars have different
>   dimensions on different devices and orientations.*

```
let image = UIImage(named: "navigationBg")!
if let navigationController = self.navigationController {
   navigationController.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(image, for: .default)
}
```

Reference: [Navigation Bars](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/UIKitUICatalog/UINavigationBar.html)