# Background image to the navigationbar iOS SWIFT

Tags: swift, image, background, uinavigationbar, navigationbar

Can somebody help me? I am trying to add a background image to the navigation bar using

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named:"navigationBarBackground"), for: .top, barMetrics: .default)
```

but as a result, I get my image being dislocated like on the picture. Thank you for your help.

[image]

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40829692/navigationbar-background-image-for-ios-10-xcode-8-1-swift-3-0 if it helps in your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

self.navigationController.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(image, 
                                                   forBarMetrics: .Default)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, well, I've finally found the answer. Dislocation was caused by Wrong image size.