# How can I add navigation bar with an image instead of a title in a UIViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

Currently this is what I have:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.setNavigationBar()
}

func setNavigationBar() {
    let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.main.bounds
    let navBar = UINavigationBar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: screenSize.width, height: 44))
    let navItem = UINavigationItem(title: "")
    let doneItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.done, target: nil, action: #selector(done))
    navItem.rightBarButtonItem = doneItem
    navBar.setItems([navItem], animated: false)
    self.view.addSubview(navBar)
}

@objc func done() { // remove @objc for Swift 3
```

The issue is that the bars title seems to be off center and the bar is very thin.

How can it be made a little thicker and with an image instead of the title?

**UPDATE:**

The first suggestion seemed to do nothing. Why is that? This is the first view controller.

Full code:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseAuth


class LoginViewController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet weak var emailField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var passwordField: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var gifView: UIImageView!

private var ref: DatabaseReference!

override func viewDidLoad() {


    let logo = UIImage(named: "q-small.png")
    let imageView = UIImageView(image:logo)
    self.navigationItem.titleView = imageView

    gifView.loadGif(name: "truck-animation")
    super.viewDidLoad()

    ref = Database.database().reference()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to put an image as the navigation bar title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/865176/how-to-put-an-image-as-the-navigation-bar-title)

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to [Swift Navigation Bar Image Title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24803178/swift-navigation-bar-image-title).

Simply use this code:

```swift
let logo = UIImage(named: "logo.png")
let imageView = UIImageView(image:logo)
self.navigationItem.titleView = imageView
```

Comment: That seemed to do nothing. Please take a look at my update.

Comment: Put `print("Image exists:", logo != nil)` and tell me what it prints. Better yet you can put a breakpoint.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are creating `UINavigationBar` programmatically and i am also assuming that you are creating app using storyboard.

`self.navigationItem` returns navigation items of your `ViewController`. But as per your code you must have created just `UINavigationBar`. So to get the title view you need `UINavigationController` of your `ViewController`.

If this is your first view of app You can add that by **embedding** your `ViewController` into Navigation Controller from Storyboard, then you don't have to add navigation bar programmatically.

After that you can use this code in `viewDidLoad()`.

```
let logo = UIImage(named: "logo.png")
let imageView = UIImageView(image:logo)
self.navigationItem.titleView = imageView
```